# Laravel auth levels

Tags: php, api, authentication, laravel-5

I'm creating something like BackOffice (BO) system. Will explain from the beginning.

There are 2 sites.

1. Front site.
2. BO site.

On front site made default Laravel auth.
On BO site made api auth over Laravel passport, and another kind of authentication (in BO site players and users could be logged in, I used guard 'players' and guard 'users').

users could login over default auth (has DB table users)
players could login only after request passed auth:api middleware.

Registration.
Player fill form on front site - new record on the front site is created.
Then front site makes api call to BO site (over laravel passport) with that new registered player data. BO site check in auth:api if all is ok - then creates new record in BO site for that new player. On this stage all is ok.

Login. Player make auth on front site - all is ok, after front site makes api call to BO site for login.
in BO also login is ok, I see dump with that player data (did Auth::guard('players')->login()).

```
    if (Auth::guard('players')->attempt(array('email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password))) {

        $loggedUser = Auth::guard('players')->user();
        $loggedUser->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $loggedUser->save();
        Auth::guard('players')->login($loggedUser, false);

        return Auth::guard('players')->user()->toArray();
    }
```

I got this

```
{"id":3,"username":"pl1","name":"Player 1","email":"pl1@mail.com"}
```

Which means all is ok.

Then I make another api call to BO (for example to logout player).
At the beginning of the action I check Auth::guard('players') - and it's null. Only guard('api') is not null, but guard('players') null.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $guards = array_keys(config('auth.guards'));
    foreach ($guards as $guard)
    {
        var_dump($guard);
        var_dump(Auth::guard($guard)->check());
    }

    dd(Auth::guard('players')->user());

    $res = Auth::guard('players')->user()->logout();
}
```

And I got

```
string(3) "web" bool(false) string(7) "players" bool(false) string(3) "api" bool(true)
null
```

Can't figure out what's wrong: of previous login request I had player guard, but after 2 seconds I make logout call - players guard null.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all you should try to narrow your problem down a bit more and afterwards you should share the code part that's problematic

Comment: Hi, I edited question, added some code in action there I do player login and another action where logout would be.

Comment: Calling logout from the user object (even though it's obtained via the guard) might have unpredictable consequences. You should call the logout directly on the guard .

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right, but I can't even obtain authenticated user from guard dd(Auth::guard('players')->user()) - returns null

Comment: As you can see in first part of code, I do Auth::guard('players')->login($loggedUser, false); directly from guard

Comment: Check the underlying guard used. An API is not generally backed by the session so make sure the player guard is not a sessionguard because it won't work unless you enable the session on the API (which is probably not what you want to do).